# Deleting a line from a Text file in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to write a script that deletes a line out of a text-based database if the header matches a field of that header. For example, I have a text file that looks like

```
Name Age Identification Wage
Micheal 25 19339 10
Jane 37 19338 10
John 21 19334 12
Peter 35 19330 30
```

I call a script, and pass the Header name and a value, and it looks for the line that contains that value under the header, and promptly deletes it. So, putting

```
./script.sh filename Identification 19334
```

Should delete the entry in the database whose Identification is 19334, so that the file now looks like this:

```
Name Age Identification Wage
Micheal 25 19339 10
Jane 37 19338 10
Peter 35 19330 30
```

How would I use an Awk script, or sed, to delete that specific line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v val=$3 -v hdr=$2 '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){if($i==hdr && NR==1){col=i;break}} if($col!=val){print}}' $1 > newfile && mv newfile $1
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk won't directly update the file, but will produce the desired output:

```
awk -v header="Identification" -v value="19334" 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) cols[$i]=i} $(cols[header])!=value' data
Name Age Identification Wage
Micheal 25 19339 10
Jane 37 19338 10
Peter 35 19330 30
```

- The variable `header` is set `Identification` using the `-v` flag
- `value` is set to value to match on using another `-v` flag
- The `cols` associative array is set up so that column headers are assigned their field numbers
- Lastly, print any line where the `header` indicated column doesn't match `value`

Multiple rows matching `value` would be deleted.

My bash-fu is weak, but will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

newFile=$(awk -v header="$2" -v value="$3" 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) cols[$i]=i
} $(cols[header])!=value' $1);

echo "$newFile" > $1
```

The bash script will:

- Assign the results of the awk script to the `newFile` variable, where `$2` is the header, `$3` is the value, and `$1` is the input file.
- Overwrite the contents of the `newFile` variable over the contents of the first arg, $1

You can run it as you've described:

```
./script.sh data Identification 19334
```

which alters the original file and produces:

```
Name Age Identification Wage
Micheal 25 19339 10
Jane 37 19338 10
Peter 35 19330 30
```

One caveat is that mispelling a header will overwrite the whole file with the original contents, and possibly leave you wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: redirecting `$newFile" > $1` is cute, but not standard practice. The typical solution is `awk '{script stuff}' file > file.new && mv file.new file`. This will only `mv` file.new when the `awk` program did NOT have any errors. Storing a giant file into a variable (like $newFile) is possible, but hard to debug when there are problems. Good luck to all.